# "No suitable applications were found" when trying to submit update to the app store

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I looked through the other questions for this, but they didn't answer my question. I'm trying to submit an update for my application, so in the iTunes Connect I clicked add a version and updated the version to 1.01.  I then went into the info.plist and updated the bundle version to 1.01.  I get the above error though when I try to submit it to the app store.  In my Manage applications it says version 1.01 prepare for upload.

Comment: Surely Apple can answer this question better than we can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than making the version change in the plist directly, use the summary tab on the project bundle's target page. Also, make sure your bundle identifier hasn't changed there either. Be sure to hit enter after any changes and check the next tab 'info' to see if the changes have reflected there. If those all match and you're still having an issue, contact apple.

Comment: What's the best way to contact apple regarding this?  I'm not seeing any obvious way from iTunes Connect.

Comment: I found the help link and walking through that found something that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to click the "Ready to Upload Binary" button before Xcode will find it.

Otherwise it's probably the precceding zero in your version number. You should use `1.1` or `1.0.1`.